# Source of the formula for divergence of vector function in spherical coordinates

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, coordinate-systems, vector-fields, spherical-coordinates

I want to calculate the divergence of the vector function $F(r,\theta, \phi)=(r^2, rsin\phi, 0)$. I assumed that in order to do this I could just calculat the divergence in spherical coordinates, which would be: $\nabla F(r,\theta, \phi)=2r$.

However, my textbook shows the result in cartesian coordinates as: $$\nabla F=\frac{1}{r^2sin\theta}[\frac{\delta}{\delta r}(r^2sin \theta F_r) + \frac{\delta}{\delta \theta}(r sin \phi F_\theta) + 
\frac{\delta}{\delta \phi}(rF_\phi)]$$

I've also seen it be appiled [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2184312/calculating-divergence-for-a-field-in-spherical-coordinates), but they don't really give any context as to where this formula comes from and it's nowhere in any of my textbooks.

Can anyone explain/point me to a good deriviation of this formula? Also why don't we take the divergent in the same coordinate system as the vector function?

Answer (score 2):

This formula comes from the chain rule, essentially. Suppose $F(r,\theta,\phi) = (F_r,F_\theta,F_\phi)$ is a vector field given in spherical coordinates (I assume this is what you mean by the notations $F_r,F_\theta,F_\phi$).

Vector fields are properly understood as differential operators. When applied to a function $g$, it means the directional derivative:
$$ F \cdot g = F_r \frac{\partial g}{\partial r} + F_\theta \frac{\partial g}{\partial \theta} + F_\phi \frac{\partial g}{\partial \phi} \tag{1} $$

If we want to change to Cartesian coordinates and write $F = (F_x,F_y,F_z)$, then this would mean that for any function $g$,
$$ F \cdot g = F_x \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} + F_y \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} + F_z \frac{\partial g}{\partial z} \tag{2} $$
You can use the chain rule to relate the two expressions. For instance,
$$ \frac{\partial g}{\partial r} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial r} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial r} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial z} \frac{\partial z}{\partial r} $$

Do the same thing for $\frac{\partial g}{\partial \theta}$ and $\frac{\partial g}{\partial \phi}$ and plug into equation (1), regroup the terms, and compare with equation (2), and you'll see:

$$ F_x = F_r \frac{\partial x}{\partial r} + F_\theta \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta} + F_\phi \frac{\partial x}{\partial \phi}, $$
and similarly for $F_y$ and $F_z$. Using the well-known formulas:
$$
\begin {align*}
x &= r \sin(\theta) \cos(\phi) \\
y &= r \sin(\theta) \sin(\phi) \\
z &= r \cos(\theta)
\end {align*}
$$
and taking the partial derivatives, you'll see that

$$ F_x = F_r \sin(\theta) \cos(\phi) + F_\theta r \cos(\theta) \cos(\phi) - F_\phi r \sin(\theta) \sin(\phi) $$
and similarly for $F_y$ and $F_z$. So you have to compute the divergence as:
$$ \nabla \cdot F = \frac{\partial F_x}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial F_y}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial F_z}{\partial z} $$

We've just computed $F_x, F_y, F_z$ in terms of $F_r,F_\theta,F_\phi$. Finally, you should use the chain rule again to evaluate $\frac{\partial F_x}{\partial x}$, etc, in terms of partial derivatives with respect to $r,\theta,\phi$. And you should get the expression you asked about in your post.

Comment: Isn't there a faster way to get to the result - without all the consecutive differentiations?

Comment: If you know some abstract differential geometry, it can probably be phrased in terms of pushforward matrices on tangent spaces, but I figured we were trying to keep it elementary.